# Redirect domain request to localhost/sub-folder

Tags: apache, ubuntu, apache2

I have an apache2 server installed on my Ubuntu installation (13.04, if it helps any) for personal programming testing and I was wondering if it might be possible to, when I type in `fakedomainname.dev`, it redirects to `localhost/testingSite`. I've looked into editing the `/etc/hosts` file, but that only allows me to redirect to an IP address, which I don't think that localhost pages have their own IP addresses (do they?) and so that doesn't work. I can access the page currently through `localhost/testingSite`, but it would be interesting to be able to enter `fakedomainname.dev` instead.

Thanks!

PS...Should this have been posted on Ask Ubuntu instead of Stack Overflow? I wasn't sure if it was considered Ubuntu specific enough, so I posted it here. If I placed it wrong, please move it!

Comment: In general SO is mostly about programming, although I am sure there is plenty of people here who can answer this. serverfault.com may be a good place to search for an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Redirect to `127.0.0.1` -- it's equivalent to localhost.

Here's my /etc/hosts file:

```
root@vagrant:~# cat /etc/hosts
127.0.0.1   localhost   stuff.dev
127.0.1.1   vagrant.vm  vagrant

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
```

I have a flask app running on port 8000, which I can now reach at stuff.dev:8000

```
root@vagrant:~# wget stuff.dev:8000
--2013-09-13 02:22:14--  http://stuff.dev:8000/
Resolving stuff.dev (stuff.dev)... 127.0.0.1
Connecting to stuff.dev (stuff.dev)|127.0.0.1|:8000... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 2 [text/html]
Saving to: ‘index.html’

100%[================================================================================================================================================================>] 2           --.-K/s   in 0s

2013-09-13 02:22:14 (229 KB/s) - ‘index.html’ saved [2/2]
```

Comment: Thanks Kyle! This allows me to redirect the fake url to localhost, but is there a way that I can redirect to one of my virtual sites? Eg. localhost/virtual-site? Thanks!

Comment: This sounds like something you need in your [VirtualHosts file](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/examples.html) for Apache, setting the document root to be based at `testingSite`.

Comment: Yeah, I thought it would eventually come down to that, I was just wondering/hoping if there would be a way to do it without shifting the document root, though it won't be too much trouble. Thanks!